# Jquery year calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function compute() {
        if ($('input[name=type]:checked').val() != undefined) {
            var a = parseInt($('input[name=LeaseCostYear1]').val());
            var b = parseInt($('input[name=LeaseCostYear2]').val());
            var c = parseInt($('input[name=LeaseCostYear3]').val());
            var d = parseInt($('input[name=LeaseCostYear4]').val());
            var e = parseInt($('input[name=LeaseCostYear5]').val());

            var total = a + b+c+d+e;
            $('#txBxLeaseNpvTotal').val(a + b + c + d + e);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-content">
        <button type="button" class="accordion">@ResourceStrings.Text_BuyVersusLease</button>
        <div class="accordion-panel">
            <table class="form-detail-table">
                <colgroup>
                    <col style="width:28%">
                    <col style="width:12%">
                    <col style="width:12%">
                    <col style="width:12%">
                    <col style="width:12%">
                    <col style="width:12%">
                    <col style="width:12%">
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <td />
                    <td class="form-label">@ResourceStrings.Text_Year1</td>
                    <td class="form-label">@ResourceStrings.Text_Year2</td>
                    <td class="form-label">@ResourceStrings.Text_Year3</td>
                    <td class="form-label">@ResourceStrings.Text_Year4</td>
                    <td class="form-label">@ResourceStrings.Text_Year5</td>
                    <td />
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="form-label">@ResourceStrings.Text_CostToLease</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LeaseCostYear1)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LeaseCostYear2)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LeaseCostYear3)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LeaseCostYear4)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LeaseCostYear5)</td>
                    <td />
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td class="form-label">@ResourceStrings.Text_NpvLease</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LeaseNpvTotal, new { id = "txBxLeaseNpvTotal" })</td>
                    <td colspan="5" />
                </tr>
               
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to do below calculation using javascript or jquery...I am trying to add all the years and display total and later multiply with NPV @ 8% - Lease.

Year 1 + NPV(0.08,Year2+0,Year3+0,Year4+0,Year5+0).

Comment: I tried using jquery but not getting any proper result..

Comment: Please do not tag jquery questions as "c#". I've corrected this for you.

Comment: Please provide me solution for this

Comment: Could you explain what is not working with your code? Can you add the corresponding HTML?

Comment: add input and expecting  output to your question

Comment: We need to look at your HTML to really understand what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: I added html details.

Comment: I have added my html code....can you please suggest what wrong with the code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to add a specific class to your inputs, so selection of all inputs could be done with one selection and then you can just iterate over them.

Second suggestion is to always provide 2nd argument to `parseInt` function, which is radix - the base you want the string to be parsed into. In most use cases it is base 10. Like so `const myInt = parseInt(someStringValue, 10);` Otherwise in some cases you might get unexpected results.

If you are unable to add a class, you can use `input[name^="LeaseCostYear"]` selector to select all inputs which name begins with "LeaseCostYear".

```
function compute() {
  if ($('input[name=type]:checked').val() != undefined) {
    const total = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="LeaseCostYear"]'))
                       .reduce((acc, el) => acc + parseInt($(el).val(), 10), 0);

    $('#txBxLeaseNpvTotal').val(total);
  }
}
```

Comment: can u suggest me any other method than this.

Comment: I updated the answer so you can select the inputs by the name, as originally.

Comment: JavaScript critical error is showing I am not able to execute this code

Comment: Error  is showing in this line.. const total = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="LeaseCostYear"]'))
                       .reduce((acc, el) => acc + parseInt($(el).val(), 10), 0);

Comment: I am not getting exactly the error in this but when i remove the code after .reduce it is taking...Can you please help me out.

Comment: What environent or browser are you running this code in?
Just tested myself, it works with inputs.

Comment: yes it started working in Microsoft Edge..but each text input value is different so not getting the total value.

Comment: Year 1 + NPV(0.08,Year2+0,Year3+0,Year4+0,Year5+0) As per the calculations above...i have to add all the years later i have to calculate present Npv at 8%...so I thought first to calculate the total of all years.

Comment: I think NPV is calculated discounting each year seperately... So you shouldn't sum them together BEFORE calculating NPV... but that's beyond the scope of this question :)

Comment: if i want to do npv calculation should i use jquery and call in controller...Do u know any particular method..I am trying to do ajax call for this.